# Cannot send mail to top domain

Tags: debian, email

I have a webserver with the domain name server1.mydomain.com, mydomain.com is currently directed to another server.

If a mail is send to an e-mail address with my top domain, eg me@mydomain.com, I get an error in the exim/mainlog 'T="Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender" from <>'.
Other mail addresses work fine.

My hosts file currently looks like this:

```
Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1       localhost
120.113.245.121          server1.mydomain.com   server1
```

Anyone an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Run Exim with test flags or debug flags and post a lot of diagnostics - https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/TestingExim - and someone *might* be able to help.

Comment: Is it possible that your server resolves mydomain.com to its own IP address, and so never considers to contact the real mydomain.com server? Try `host -t MX mydomain.com` to figure out where it wants to send the mail, and also try 1) `host mydomain.com` 2) `host <domain that host -t MX returned>`.

Comment: I got it to work by setting up a new domainname to house the server, so now it's server1.mydomain-ops.com. And followed these steps http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=16 to remove everything that refers to the old domain. This way the server stuff and my mail are separated, which is a safer setup to start with I guess.